# MicroK8S deploy webserver

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am playing with microk8s and I am trying to deploy nextcloud to get more familiar with it. However the deployment of nextcloud went fine, I am facing some issues with setting ingress for that. Maybe you could take a look at my manifests and ingress resource and help find me the problem.

This is the deployment file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: nextcloud
  name: nextcloud-service
  labels:
    run: nextcloud-app
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: nextcloud-app
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: nextcloud
  name: nextcloud-deployment
  labels:
    app: nextcloud-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nextcloud-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nextcloud-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nextcloud:latest
        name: nextcloud
        env:
        - name: NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: nextcloud-configuration
              key: nextcloud_admin_user
        - name: NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: nextcloud-secret
              key: admin_password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nextcloud-pv
          mountPath: /var/www/html/data
      volumes:
      - name: nextcloud-pv
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nextcloud-pv-claim
```

and this is the ingress resource file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nextcloud-ingress
  namespace: nextcloud
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nextcloud
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nextcloud-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Following addons are enabled on my microk8s:

- dns
- ingress

Now I would like to show you some k8s output.

**kubectl -n nextcloud describe svc nextcloud-service**

```
Name:              nextcloud-service
Namespace:         nextcloud
Labels:            run=nextcloud-app
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          run=nextcloud-app
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.152.183.189
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

**kubectl -n nextcloud describe ingress nextcloud-ingress**

```
Name:             nextcloud-ingress
Namespace:        nextcloud
Address:          192.168.60.2
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /nextcloud   nextcloud-service:80   <none>)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                 From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  11m                 nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  11m                 nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
  Normal  UPDATE  63s (x22 over 11m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
  Normal  UPDATE  63s (x22 over 11m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
```

**kubectl -n ingress logs pod/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-k2q6c**

```
I1024 19:56:37.955953       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress status from [{192.168.60.2 }] to [{127.0.0.1 }]
W1024 19:56:37.963861       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 19:56:37.964276       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192287", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
I1024 19:56:39.491960       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192295", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
W1024 19:56:41.297313       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 19:57:37.955734       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress status from [{192.168.60.2 }] to [{127.0.0.1 }]
W1024 19:57:37.969214       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 19:57:37.969711       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192441", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
I1024 19:57:39.492467       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192446", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
W1024 19:57:41.302640       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 19:58:37.956198       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress status from [{192.168.60.2 }] to [{127.0.0.1 }]
W1024 19:58:37.964655       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 19:58:37.965017       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192592", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
I1024 19:58:39.493436       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192600", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
W1024 19:58:41.298097       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 19:59:37.955569       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress status from [{192.168.60.2 }] to [{127.0.0.1 }]
W1024 19:59:37.964975       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 19:59:37.965045       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192746", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
I1024 19:59:39.491840       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192750", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
W1024 19:59:41.298496       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 20:00:37.956061       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress status from [{192.168.60.2 }] to [{127.0.0.1 }]
W1024 20:00:37.965139       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 20:00:37.965212       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192896", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
I1024 20:00:39.489924       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192904", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
W1024 20:00:41.298762       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 20:01:37.955481       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress status from [{192.168.60.2 }] to [{127.0.0.1 }]
W1024 20:01:37.963612       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 20:01:37.963681       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"193049", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
I1024 20:01:39.490523       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"193058", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
W1024 20:01:41.297141       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
```

Calling http://k8s.ip/nextcloud results with 503. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: You are receiving `503` code because you have a missmatch in your `Service` -> `.spec.selector` (`run: nextcloud-app`) and your `Deployment` -> `.spec.selector.matchLabels` (`app: nextcloud-app`). You will need to have them both the same. You can see it also when describing the service (no `endpoint`). Please tell if it solved your issue.

Comment: Yes, it seems to solved the issue. Now I have another problem facing HSTS. I've tried to add tls-secret with self signed certificate, but firefox won't accept it. Need the service to listen on 443? I though, the HSTS should handle that and redirect the port 80 to 443. What about the app within container. Is it necessary, the app inside listens on 443 too od it doesn't matter?

Comment: Please consider creating another question with details specific to your new issue (`HSTS`) as per rule of [one question = one post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). The port listening inside of a `Pod` doesn't matter as long as it's referenced correctly in `targetPort` (service). You can listen for traffic on port `12345` inside of a pod and with Kubernetes networking you will be able to connect to it with for example [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource on port 80/443 (`curl LB_IP:80`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in the comments:

> You are receiving 503 code because you have a missmatch in your `Service` -> `.spec.selector` (`run: nextcloud-app`) and your `Deployment` -> `.spec.selector.matchLabels` (`app: nextcloud-app`). You will need to have them both the same. You can see it also when describing the service (no endpoint).

The issue in this particular setup is that there is a missmatch between a `matchLabel` in a `Deployment` and `selector` in the `Service`:

`Deployment`

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nextcloud-app # <-- HERE!
```

`Service`:

```yaml
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: nextcloud-app # <-- HERE!
```

To fix that you will need to have both of them matching (for example):

- `app: nextcloud-app` in a `Deployment` and a `Service`

---

Some of the ways to identify mismatched selector (by using examples from post):

- Manual inspection of `YAML` definitions as shown above
- `$ kubectl -n nextcloud describe svc nextcloud-service`

```yaml
Name:              nextcloud-service
Namespace:         nextcloud
Labels:            run=nextcloud-app
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          run=nextcloud-app
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.152.183.189
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         <none> # <-- HERE
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Above `describe` shows that the service is created but there are no `endpoints` (`Pods`) to send the traffic to.

> No endpoint could be also related to the fact that `Pod` is not `Ready` or is not in `Healthy` state

- `$ kubectl get endpoint -n nextcloud`

```
NAME                 ENDPOINTS            AGE
nextcloud-service    <none>               1m
```

- Logs from `Ingress` controller (posted in the question):

```sh
I1024 19:56:37.955953       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress status from [{192.168.60.2 }] to [{127.0.0.1 }]
W1024 19:56:37.963861       6 controller.go:909] Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1024 19:56:37.964276       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"nextcloud", Name:"nextcloud-ingress", UID:"913dcf73-e5df-4ad9-a23b-22d6ad8b83a7", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"192287", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress nextcloud/nextcloud-ingress
```

`<--REDACTED--> Service "nextcloud/nextcloud-service" does not have any active Endpoint.`

---

I encourage you to check the Helm chart of nextcloud:

- *[Github.com: Nextcloud: Helm: Charts: Nextcloud](https://github.com/nextcloud/helm/tree/master/charts/nextcloud)*
- *[Microk8s.io: Docs: Commands](https://microk8s.io/docs/commands)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*
- *[Microk8s.io: Docs: Addon Ingress](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-ingress)*